# How to check for specific value in array

Tags: c, arrays, count

I have a 2D array that contains an X value anytime the user put's down a chess piece there. [image: 2D array in C]

I'd like to count the X values with the following code:

```
void tableSum(int N, int table[N][N]) {
    int row,col;
    int count = 0;

    for(row=0; row<N; row++) {
        for(col=0;col<N;col++) {
            if(table[row][col] == 'x') {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nNumber of X: %d\n", count);
}
```

If I change the X to a number in the table and try to search for that it's working so I'm pretty sure my problem is in the 'if' part.

EDIT: I also changed int table[N][N] to char table[N][N] earlier in my code, not helping.

EDIT2: Added the whole code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXPOSITION 100

int tableSize(int size) {
    printf("Set table size to: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    getchar();
    return size;
}

void inputPosition(int pos_size, char position[pos_size]) {
    int i;
    for (int i = 0; i < pos_size / 2; i++)
    {
        printf("%d. piece: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%2s", &position[2 * i]);
        if (position[2 * i] == 'x')
        {
            position[2 * i] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }
}

void tableMaker(int N, char table[N][N], char positions[] ) {

    int row, col, i;

    for(row=0; row<N; row++){
        for(col=0; col<N; col++){
            table[row][col]=0;
        }
    }

    i=0;
    while(positions[i]!=0){
        col=positions[i]-'A';
        i++;
        row=positions[i]-'1';
        i++;
        table[row][col]++;
    }
}

void tableOut(int N ,char table[N][N]) {
    int row, col;

    printf("    ");
    for(col=0; col<N; col++){
      printf("%c ", col+'A');
    };
    printf("\n");

    for(row=0; row<N; row++){
        printf("%2d |", row+1);
        for(col=0; col<N; col++){
            if(table[row][col]==0){
                printf(".|");
            }else{
                printf("x|");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void tableSum(int N, char table[N][N]) {
    int row, col;
    int count = 0;


    for(row=0; row<N; row++) {
        for(col=0;col<N;col++) {
            if(table[row][col] == 'x') {
                count++;
            }

        }
    }
    printf("\nNumber of X: %d\n", count);
}



int main () {
    //Set table size
    int N = tableSize(N);
    char table[N][N];
    //Ask for positions
    char positions[MAXPOSITION];
    inputPosition(sizeof(positions), positions);
    //Table functions
    tableMaker(N,table,positions);
    printf("Table:\n");
    tableOut(N,table);
    tableSum(N,table);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `int table[N][N]` should be `char table[N][N]`

Comment: @EdHeal This shouldn't be an issue, as long as the caller uses 'x', too (C stores `char`s as `ints`, anyway). OP, why don't you print `table[row][col]` which is expected to be an 'x'? Is it indeed an 'x'? Same lower case?

Comment: @EdHeal Thanks for the insight, earlier I changed my code to char because I thought I can't compare an int and a char but it's not helping. I also edited my post with this information.

Comment: Should `'x'` be `'X'`

Comment: @DYZ - Chars are not stored as ints. Use `sizeof` to prove this is the case- http://ideone.com/Y3R0IJ

Comment: @EdHeal Everytime the user put's down a piece on the table it will be an x, i double checked my code it's not a big X, also tried it but not helping.

Comment: @EdHeal `int main(void) {printf("%d\n", sizeof ('a'));}` ---> 4

Comment: @M.Carver Could you print `table[row][col]` _in the function_ and make sure it is indeed an 'x'? Also, please show the caller code.

Comment: @DYZ - In your example 'a' is promoted to int. Try `int main(void) {char a;printf("%d\n", sizeof (a));}`

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. From the code shown, you are either passing the wrong value for `N` or the wrong array or, the array does not contain any `x`.

Comment: Code posted code is fine - see http://ideone.com/JvsOxn  The problem is in some code you didn't post. Show how the table is initialized and how you call the function.

Comment: *"If I change the X to a number in the table and try to search for that it's working so I'm pretty sure my problem is in the 'if' part."*. I'm not sure what you mean here. Your code looks like it works.

Comment: I added the whole code, @RoadRunner If i fill the table e.g. with the number 3 and search for that it works. If i fill the table with x| and search for that it's not. Sorry for my English. :)

Comment: As far as I can see there you never assign the value `'x'` to a position in the table.

Comment: @4386427 I assign x| in the else part, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: I can't find it! You do `printf("x|");` but I can't see the assignment. Please point to the line where you think you put `'x'`in the table

Comment: You are using `x` to terminate the input. So assuming that remains in the input array, you will get 1 `x` at most.

Comment: The `inputPosition` function looks broken. What is your input?

Comment: @4386427 he got it from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41528541/how-to-scanf-multiple-values-and-add-to-an-array).

Comment: @4386427 Yes it's my other question. Thanks for the help all of you guys, I figured it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code. If we forget them for a moment and look at the current code then we can try to figure out what the code is doing.

In `inputPosition` it seems you expect an input like `"A1B4C4x"` which you change to `"A1B4C4'\0'"`, i.e. you change the `x` to a zero-termination.

Then here:

```
i=0;
while(positions[i]!=0){
    col=positions[i]-'A';
    i++;
    row=positions[i]-'1';
    i++;
    table[row][col]++;   // <------ obs
}
```

you count how many times each board position was present in the input. So if the input was `"A1A1x"` you would end up with `table[0][0]` being 2 and all other entries being 0.

Maybe you wanted to do:

```
i=0;
while(positions[i]!=0){
    col=positions[i]-'A';
    i++;
    row=positions[i]-'1';
    i++;
    table[row][col] = 'x';
}
```

This would put an `'x'` in the input positions instead of doing a count.

Also I'll suggest that you add some validation of the input. Currently it is very easy to make your program crash. For instance I could set the board size to 4 and input `"XXXXXXx"` which would make your program do accesses outside the `table` boundary.

Comment: OH. I actually wanted to count how many times a chess piece represents itself. Every 0 is '.|' and every other number is 'x|'. But it's a great idea to change it to 'x', didn't even think about it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (position[2 * i] == 'x')
    {
        position[2 * i] = '\0';
        break;
    }
```

you use 'x' to end the input

Answer (score 0):

I think I just found the problem with the help of the community.

As I stated in my post I try to find the 'x' value but it seems I didn't assign it to the table. Earlier I filled up the table with numbers:  0 if there is no chess piece and other numbers if the user put down a chess piece.

I use the following code now and it's working perfectly:

```
void tableSum(int N, char table[N][N]) {
    int row, col;
    int count = 0;


    for(row=0; row<N; row++) {
        for(col=0;col<N;col++) {
            if(table[row][col] != 0) {
                count++;
            }

        }
    }
    printf("\nNumber of X: %d\n", count);
}
```

It doesn't matter if the user tried to put down more than one chess piece on the same field because every number that greater than 0 is represented by x in my code. This is a great example on how to overthink problems as a beginner programmer. Thanks for your time!